# Convergence of the probability that the sum of the numbers drawn from a given distribution exceeds a given value.

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Question from an old test:

> The bakery produces doughnuts with weights $W_1 \text{g}, W_2 \text{g}, W_3 \text{g}, \ldots$, where $W_i$ for each doughnut is drawn from a distribution with a finite expected value $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Let $p_n$ denote the probability that the weight of $n$ doughnuts exceeds $n \mu+5 \sigma \sqrt{n}$.
> What can be said about the convergence of the sequence $p_n$, if:
>
> - (a) the weight of each doughnut is independent, and $W_i$ has a normal distribution  (weight can be negative).
> - (b) the weight of each doughnut is independent, the distribution of $W_i$ is the same for each doughnut, but not necessarily normal.
> - (c) each doughnut has the same weight $W_i=W$ drawn from a normal distribution.
>
> (possible answers: (A) it is a constant sequence, (B) converges to $0$, (C) converges to $1$, (D) converges to $\frac{1}{2}$, (E) converges to another value, (F) divergent, (G) not enough information)

My answers are:

(a) - B, because it means that on average the weight of each doughnut will exceed $5$ standard deviations, and the more drawings there are, the smaller is the probability of this happening.

(b) - B, because from the [CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) I know that it's the same situation as if we were choosing weights from a normal distribution (regardless of what the true distribution is), so reasoning is the same as in (a).

(c) - D, because if $n$ tends to infinity, then the term $\sigma \sqrt{n}$ in $n \mu+5 \sigma \sqrt{n}$ will be negligible, and the probability that we exceed the expected value is $\frac{1}{2}$. However, I have doubts about this, because in the same way one could say that in (a) and (b) it is also $\frac{1}{2}$.

Are these correct answers? If not, where is the flaw in the reasoning?

**Edit:**
After another try I got that in (a) and (b) the probability is constant and equal to $1- \Phi(5)$. I derived this from transforming the formula
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  P(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}) - n\mu}{\sqrt{n}\sigma} \leq \alpha) = \Phi(\alpha)
$$
to obtain
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  P(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i} \leq \alpha \cdot \sqrt{n}\sigma + n\mu) = \Phi(\alpha)
$$

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  P(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i} > 5 \cdot \sqrt{n}\sigma + n\mu) = 1-\Phi(5).
$$

Comment: The question asks about $n \mu+5 \sigma \sqrt{n}$.  What does the CLT actually say? How can you translate the question to match it?

Comment: Your argument for (c) is flawed, but that does not mean your answer of D is wrong.

Comment: @Henry CLT says that the mean of multiple independent random variables with the same distribution approximates a normal distribution. The question mentions the sum of the weights of the doughnuts, but I guess you have to think of it as the average weight of one doughnut instead of the sum. So we are looking at the probability that the average weight of $n$ doughnuts will exceed $\mu + \frac{5\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: The detail of the CLT will help you answer (b).  There is no need for a limit in (a), since the sum of independent normal random variables has a normal distribution with mean equal to the sum of means and variance equal to the sum of the variances.

Comment: @Henry I have edited the post. I hope this is the detail you had in mind. Still, I have no other idea for (c).

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about what distribution the total weight of $n$ doughnuts has.

In (a) it is $N(n\mu,n\sigma^2)$, and so $p_n=1-\Psi(5)$.

In (b) it is only approximately $N(n\mu,n\sigma^2)$, and so $p_n\to1-\Psi(5)$.

In (c) it is $N(n\mu,n^2\sigma^2)$, and so $p_n=1-\Psi(5/\sqrt n)\to1-\Psi(0)=1/2$.

Comment: In (c), there's $n^2$ next to the $\sigma^2$ because of $\text{Var}(nX) = n^2\text{Var}(X)$? All the rest is clear. Thanks for your answer.